# Не сохраняется прогресс. Как добавить функцию автосохранения/или функцию сохранения?

Tags: java, javafx, save

Не могу сохранить прогресс

```
package sudoku.persistance;

import sudoku.problemdomain.IStorage;
import sudoku.problemdomain.SudokuGame;

import java.io.*;

public class LocalStorageImpl implements IStorage {
    private static File GAME_DATA = new File (
            System.getProperty ("user.home"),
            "gamedata.txt"
    );

    @Override
    public void updateGameData(SudokuGame game) throws IOException {
        try {
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(GAME_DATA);
            ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOutputStream);
            objectOutputStream.writeObject(game);
            objectOutputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IOException("Unable to access Game Data");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public SudokuGame getGameData() throws IOException {
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(GAME_DATA);
        ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(fileInputStream);

        try {
            SudokuGame gameState = (SudokuGame) objectInputStream.readObject();
            objectInputStream.close();
            return gameState;
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new IOException("File Not Found");
        }
    }
}
```

Методы зовутся в двух классах:
`SudokuBuildLogic`:

```
package sudoku.buildlogic;

import sudoku.computationlogic.GameLogic;
import sudoku.persistance.LocalStorageImpl;
import sudoku.problemdomain.IStorage;
import sudoku.problemdomain.SudokuGame;
import sudoku.userinterface.IUserInterfaceContract;
import sudoku.userinterface.logic.ControlLogic;

import java.io.IOException;

public class SudokuBuildLogic {
    public static void build (IUserInterfaceContract.View userInterface) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        SudokuGame initialState;
        IStorage storage = new LocalStorageImpl();

        try {
            initialState = storage.getGameData();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            initialState = GameLogic.getNewGame();
            storage.updateGameData(initialState);
        }

        IUserInterfaceContract.EventListener uiLogic
                = new ControlLogic(storage, userInterface);

        userInterface.setListener(uiLogic);
        userInterface.updateBoard(initialState);
    }
}
```

И в `ControlLogic`:

```
package sudoku.userinterface.logic;

import sudoku.computationlogic.GameLogic;
import sudoku.constants.GameState;
import sudoku.constants.Messages;
import sudoku.problemdomain.IStorage;
import sudoku.problemdomain.SudokuGame;
import sudoku.userinterface.IUserInterfaceContract;

import java.io.IOException;

public class ControlLogic implements IUserInterfaceContract.EventListener {

    private IStorage storage;

    private IUserInterfaceContract.View view;

    public ControlLogic(IStorage storage, IUserInterfaceContract.View view) {
        this.storage = storage;
        this.view = view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSudokuInput(int x, int y, int input) {
        try {
            SudokuGame gameData = storage.getGameData();
            int [][] newGridState = gameData.getCopyOfGridState();
            newGridState[x][y] = input;

            gameData = new SudokuGame(
                    GameLogic.checkForCompletion(newGridState),
                    newGridState
            );

            storage.updateGameData(gameData);

            view.updateSquare(x, y, input);

            if (gameData.getGameState() == GameState.COMPLETE) {
                view.showDialog (Messages.GAME_COMPLETE);
            }

        } catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            view.showError(Messages.ERROR);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDialogClick() {
        try {
            storage.updateGameData(
                    GameLogic.getNewGame()
            );

            view.updateBoard(storage.getGameData());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            view.showError(Messages.ERROR);
        }
    }
}
```

Метод getGameData() зовётся здесь:

```
package sudoku.problemdomain;

import java.io.IOException;

public interface IStorage {
    void updateGameData (SudokuGame game) throws IOException;
    SudokuGame getGameData () throws IOException;
}
```

Далее не разбираюсь

Вот весь код: https://github.com/shodmon/JavaDesktopSudokuDemo

Comment: Что будет если пользователь начнёт новую игру? файл пере запишется?

А так как у вас есть координаты х  и у, то можно по ним ориентироваться, на каждую введённую цифру вызывать запись- это для теста.

Если всё отработает штатно, то переделать в отдельный метод, который будет вызываться при закрытие приложения и записывать в файл все данные. Но надо записывать всё.

Comment: @Kakius, когда запускаю приложение, оно сохраняет сразу в  "c:\Users\${current_user_name}\gamedata.txt". Далее, не зависимо от того есть ли изменения или нет, в последующем открывается со старого gamedata.txt, но без прогресса, а так как начиналась версия рандомки (то есть новый рандом не проигрывает, что хорошо). Сейчас, учу Java, как создавать кнопки и правила сохранения, чтобы вручную спрашивать, хочет ли юзер сохранить игру.

Comment: @Kakius То есть новая игра не начинается вообще, пока не удалить gamedata.txt. А когда приложение открывается во второй раз, не проходя игру до конца, открывается раскладка номеров с первого запуска, а не новая. Как-то так. Нужно создать кнопки новая игра, сохранить и загрузить. Пока не могу этого сделать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так :

```
     @Override
        public void updateGameData(SudokuGame obj) throws IOException {
if (GAME_DATA.exists()) GAME_DATA.delete();
            try (final ObjectOutputStream outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(GAME_DATA)))) {
                outputStream.writeObject(obj);
                outputStream.flush();
            } 
        }
    
        @Override    
        public SudokuGame getGameData() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
            try (final ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(GAME_DATA)))) {
                return (SudokuGame)is.readObject();
            } 
        }
```

Comment: Не сохраняется. Но спасибо.

Comment: Я добавил два класса, откуда зову методы.

Comment: @Shodmon простите, что значит "не сохраняется"? это объяснение на уровне "не работает". код для сохранения/чтения объекта гарантировано рабочий. возникает вопрос , что у вас за переменная File, вызываются ли данные методы? и "не работает"? - это исключение? что в этой переменной System.getProperty ("user.home") ?

Comment: ваш код тоже не работает. Файл сохраняется по этому аддрессу "user.home". То есть c:\Users\${current_user_name}. Там сохраняется в виде "gamedata.txt". Я следовал туториалу. Сам пока не полностью разобрался.

Comment: @Shodmon вы будете смеяться, но цель моего кода - именно сохранение/чтение в файл по указанному пути. именно поэтому я не понимаю формулировки"не работает". возникает справедливый вопрос: что в таком случае вы ожидаете от этого кода?

Comment: не сохраняется. Я пытаюсь разобраться. Кстати, у меня выдаёт ошибку `WARNING: Unsupported JavaFX configuration: classes were loaded from 'unnamed module @...`, но приложение открывается. Это может повлиять на сохранение?

Comment: как я ответил другому выше: когда запускаю приложение, оно сохраняет сразу в  "c:\Users\${current_user_name}\gamedata.txt". Далее, не зависимо от того есть ли изменения или нет, в последующем открывается со старого gamedata.txt, но без прогресса, а так как начиналась версия рандомки (то есть новый рандом не проигрывает, что хорошо). Сейчас, учу Java, как создавать кнопки и правила сохранения, чтобы вручную спрашивать, хочет ли юзер сохранить игру.

Comment: @Shodmon нет, это не может быть причиной проблемы. попробуйте в метод записи добавить проверку на наличие файла , возможно, он просто не перезаписывается. if (GAME_DATA.exists()) GAME_DATA.delete(); ответ исправил

Comment: Попробовал, не получилось. Ну да ладно) Спасибо огромное за попытки

Comment: @Shodmon в классе UserInterfaceImpl в методе public void handle(KeyEvent event) уберите строку ((TextField) event.getSource()).setText(""); и все будет работать. тут проблема не в сохранении, как вы ее описали, а в логике вашей программы

Comment: ошибка была в том же методе в строке `else if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.BACK_SPACE); {`. Нечаянно поставил `;` в конце `if`. Ну и `((TextField) event.getSource()).setText("");` незачем. Её тоже убрал. Спасибо!

Comment: Что делать с вопросом? Вопрос не по теме. Удалить? Чтобы его не закрыли

Comment: @Shodmon ничего не делайте)) может кому-то пригодится информация по записи/чтению объектов